# Pointing to pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

This piece of code no matter how hard I tried I can't understand...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ***mat;

    mat = new int**[4];

    for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
        mat[h] = new int*[4];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        delete[] mat[i];
        delete[] mat;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't this `mat = new int**[4];` mean that mat would point to a `int**` array, so when I want to use a member of this array I should do `*mat[0]`?

I don't get this line `mat[h] = new int*[4];`.

Comment: `mat[0]` is a member of that array. `mat[0][0]` is a member of the array pointed into by `mat[0]`.   (In case you are unaware, `*X` is another way of writing `X[0]`, when we are dealing with arrays or pointers).  `mat[h]` is a member of that array also. The line you don't "get" is making this member point to the first element of an array which is being freshly allocated.

Comment: If you say to yourself "point to the first element of an array" instead of "point to an array" it might be less confusing

Comment: You have to be careful when calling a pointer "an array", because while a pointer *can* point to an array (or rather, its first element), a pointer to a pointer is not the same as an array of arrays.

Comment: A pointer & an array are different from each other. (e.g. `&array==&array[0]==array`, ignoring the data types. But `&ptr != &ptr[0]`). But in many cases, the compiler translates the syntaxes from each other. `*(a+i) <-> a[i]`. So just be cautious, especially when using multi-dimentional arrays.

Comment: okay,i never knew you could do 

int *cat;
cout << cat[2];                 , what does cat[anything] mean?

Comment: @anishsane data types are an integral part of pointers, it does not make much sense to say "ignoring the data types" along with an example that doesn't compile. You have to convert the pointers in order to make that equality comparison.  Especially if someone is unclear about what the differences are between those things.

Comment: `*(a+i)` is **always** equivalent to `a[i]`, for primitive types (i.e. not class objects with overloaded operator)

Comment: @user3810737. `cat[2]` there means:  Precondition - `cat` is a pointer that points to an element of an array.  Result - the element of that array after the one after the one being pointed to.

Comment: Congratulations! You just won the prestigious [3-star programmer award](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: When we use generic functions like `free`, we often use `void*` pointers. Same is the case for some call-back functions. Though, this is confusing, we do use this kind of programming.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a step-by step explanation in terms of inscribed comments and also corrected code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int ***mat; // placeholder for a 3D matrix, three dimensional storage of integers
    // say for 3d matrix, you have height(z-dimension), row and columns
    mat = new int**[4]; // allocate for one dimension, say height
    for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
        mat[h] = new int*[4]; // allocate 2nd dimension, say for rows per height
    }
    // now you should allocate space for columns (3rd dimension)
    for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
       for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
          mat[h][r] = new int[4]; // allocate 3rd dimension, say for cols per row
    }}
    // now you have the matrix ready as 4 x 4 x 4 
    // for deallocation, delete column first, then row, then height
    // rule is deallocate in reverse order of allocation
    for(int h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
       for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
          delete [] mat[h][r]; // deallocate 3rd dimension, say for cols per row
       }
       delete [] mat[h]; // deallocate 2nd dimension, rows per height
    }
    delete [] mat; // deallocate height, i.e. entire matrix
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one level of 'pointership' is implicit

```
new int;
```

will give you an `int*`, and so will

```
new int[3];
```

move you way upwards from there